# Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

[image: my result after run my spring application]

I'm very new in spring boot and trying to build a microservices project using spring boot by referring to tutorial but i'm getting this error. While try to retrieve localhost:8888 i got this "localhost refused to connect". I already try to change server port but still get the same outcome. Please help me.Why did i get this connection refuse? FYI:  i try to connect my spring cloud config server to git.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? And share the code snippets of your app that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Please try and add an actual question.

Comment: You need to make sure that configuration server is actually running on the port 8888.

Comment: Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888,Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available .. is this shows that its running on the port 8888?

Answer (score 0):

i too has the same issue
i had two spring boot application - LS and SCCS
the port used for LS is 8080
the port used for SCCS is 8888

i tried to pass all the configuration of LS to SCCS and  tried to run the LS ....I got the connection timeout error...
instead...
u run the SCCS first.. which is configured in 8888... it works fine

hope this answers your question